# how to spot corruption of this during contruction

Tags: c++, pointers, constructor, this

I am building an object from a pointer to the same class.

```
 class CA {
 public:
    CA(CA *p) {       #1
      //here 'this' is 0x7fffffffdfb0
    }

    CA(const CA& o){} #2

    CA() {            #3
      // here all fine.
    }
 };

 // create variable.
 CA a(new CA());
```

When I want o create a variable like above I can see that at the beginning of the call of  constructor #1, the object starts with `this` set to `0x7fffffffdfb0`. Constructor #3 is ok.

Is it allowed to do that?

I thought that my code might corrupt somewhere the object but I don't know how to spot/identify who is doing it?

If I use `valgrind` it doesn't complain.

I am using gcc in Cent Os.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your code is working, and you're not getting any complaint from valgrind, but you aren't happy with the address your `this` has been assigned so that's what you're posting about?

Comment: this is pointing to somewhere in the memory, generally you should not take care of its numerical value.

Comment: I am assuming that is not a valid address or am I wrong?

Comment: why do you think it's not valid?

Comment: it is pretty big value

Comment: I hope it doesn't come as a surprise that "big" is subjective. Your OS doesn't really care about your perception of values. Bits are bits. If it's valid, it's valid, even if the value looks strange to you.

Comment: If you write `int x;` after `CA a(new CA());` then what does `&x` look like?

Answer (score 1):

Your `CA()` is called by the `new` and thus points to your heap, while your `CA(CA *p)` is called when instantiating `a` on the stack and thus points to a totally different part of your memory.

So, yes, this is correct and expected.

#### Further explanation

Your operating system (and C++ runtime) are absolutely free to set the actual value of the pointer. Looking at your question you seem to be using a x86_64 Linux, therefore you are using a virtual memory system, which means that it can map physical memory to (just about) any point in the virtual address space your program is running in.

In fact, 0x7fffffffdfb0 fits in 47 bits, and is therefore in the lower 0.000763% of your memory space - and thus realistically speaking a very, very small value.

Comment: Yes, I am indeed saying that your code piece is behaving correctly. If you need further explanation, please tell me what you would expect to happen instead.

Comment: Hi. No you are perfectly fine. I had a crash yesterday on that and I thought that it was that address. I've just found that the problem was somewhere else. Thanks a lot.